# SpreadsheetApp.getLastRows() provides empty records and not truncate to those with data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to JS and use of Google App Script, so pardon my lack of JS knowledge.

I got a simple .gs script to work. It converts content in one cell to a hyperlink (e.g. if text is "blah", it would be "https://example.com/blah").

The script retrieves the number of rows to operate on. For one sheet, this does it correctly and truncates it to the last entry (row=31) even though the sheet has 1000 rows. However, for another sheet, it does not and returns 999:

Here's the debug for when it wasn't right:

```
Apr 8, 2022, 11:20:53 AM    Debug   doiColumn: 10   numRows: 999
```

Here it is for another sheet that worked as intended:

```
Apr 8, 2022, 9:44:47 AM Debug   doiColumn: 5   numRows: 31
```

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()) say: "Returns the position of the last row that has content."

For illustration, here is a snippet of the code:

```
let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const column = getColumn(sheet, column_name);
let range = sheet.getRange(2, column, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
console.log(range.getValues());
const numRows = range.getNumRows();
console.log(`column: ${column}   numRows: ${numRows}`)
```

I would like to make sure that `.getLawRow()` is truncated. Otherwise this script runs longer than it should.

Comment: If you have formulas especially array formulas then that will mess the up the calculation of get last row in that case I use a function called getColumnHeight().  I'll provide it  below if I can fit it.

Comment: I do have `ArrayFormula` so this is likely the problem.

Comment: I never use formulas of any kind in by own projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I could not fit it into a comment

It requires col = column number, sh =  sheet (not the name) ,ss = Spreadsheet (not the name)

```
function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
  //const h = Utilities.formatString('col: %s len: %s', col, rcA.length - s);
  //Logger.log(h);
  //SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(h).setWidth(150).setHeight(100), 'Col Length')
}
```

There are other ways to do it but I prefer this one.  It's been reliable for me

Using ranges like this sheet.getRange("A1:Z") will also provide you will a bunch of nulls from getLastRow() to getMaxRows() which then need to be filter out but if you do have a null within your data then that will also get removed and now you have bogus data because that row being removed now messes up your row order.

Comment: I picked this solution because it was easy to understand and flowed with existing functional style of coding. I did end up calling the function `getLastDataRow` (borrowed it from Mike).

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `.getLastRow()` by

```
.getLastDataRow(column)
```

and add this prototype function

```
Object.prototype.getLastDataRow = function(col){
  var lastRow = this.getLastRow();
  if (col == null){col=1}
  var range = this.getRange(lastRow,col);
  if (range.getValue() !== "") {
    return lastRow;
  } else {
    return range.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.UP).getRow();
  }  
};
```

Comment: I like this solution, but am not too familiar with prototype and so it took a bit longer to implement. But I did upvote it because it does work with some small improvements (`this` -> `sheet`).